# Unable to verify RSA signature using configured PublicKey. Signature length not correct: got 255 but was expecting 256

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, rsa

I am trying to learn how to use `RSA` public-private key pair to sign JWT.

I generated key pair using `openssl`.

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

---

I am setting environment varibles as below

```
export PRIVATE_KEY_DEMO=`cat private_key.pem`

export PUBLIC_KEY_DEMO=`cat public_key.pem`
```

---

I have following functions that create `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey`

```
public PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, URISyntaxException {
    String key = env.getProperty("PRIVATE_KEY_DEMO");
    key = key.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
         .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
         .replace("\n", "");

    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(key);

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}

private PublicKey getPublicKey() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, URISyntaxException {

    String key = env.getProperty("PUBLIC_KEY_DEMO");
    key = key.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLICKEY-----", "").replace("\n", "");
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(key);

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec((keyBytes));
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

I am able to get `JWT` token, however, I am not able to generate `PublicKey`
Below is ExceptionStack:

```
java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 255 but was expecting 256
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1222) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:655) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.RsaSignatureValidator.doVerify(RsaSignatureValidator.java:63) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.RsaSignatureValidator.isValid(RsaSignatureValidator.java:47) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.DefaultJwtSignatureValidator.isValid(DefaultJwtSignatureValidator.java:47) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:351) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong and if it can be implemented in better way.

---

**Edit**

Below are the methods I am using to generate/validate JWT.

```
public String generateToken()
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, URISyntaxException {

    PrivateKey privateKey = this.getPrivateKey();

    Date date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    String jws;

    jws = Jwts.builder()
                .setAudience("jws-consumers")
                .setIssuer("jws-issuer")
                .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT")
                .setHeaderParam("alg", "RS256")
                .setExpiration(date)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setSubject("nish")
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, privateKey)
                .compact();
    return jws;
}

public Object validateToken(String token) throws ExpiredJwtException, MalformedJwtException, SignatureException,
        IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    return Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(getPublicKey())
            .parse(token)
            .getBody();
}
```

---

Here is a sample of generated JWT

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJqd3MtY29uc3VtZXJzIiwiaXNzIjoiandzLWlzc3VlciIsImV4cCI6MTU1MDE2NDc0NCwiaWF0IjoxNTUwMTYxMTQ0LCJzdWIiOiJuaXNoIn0.EbNzMIUc4HE6CwIDyURdYF-tE4z7rzM9_GbHpB-TlRror9HRO5bmGgXR7x9HOazmL3cTUPMd46s7QJ9cU_HIJYQu9pYIQzu3V2WZf0zpFevtFxBbGDU_UCM1fbdsgSrd8APSKt_mXbJGdzIA8L7O6gBnpvNowgEuNHYgMiRwL89GrT17c31WwIWSRfRubn-bYU62pd5wm5pMArvGBYi6f6EAoIdYsK-nlhKjOIsxjGigjYAohoooV_xv36_q5_8Iaxppl2yroxCeYCy6Jp9po3bjoLVu3k9vkD_-yUGoXr9e-LCktSS4Ndxq4KCVRI_Cf5Ix_ImcZrqFZLdb4UWGmA
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/nirav24/jjwt-asymmetric-keys/tree/master)

Comment: Since the problem is that the signature you are passing to the `verify()` method is too short, that's the code you should post. How are you handling the byte array between the `sign()` operation and `verify()`?

Comment: I am running two project: I sign the JWT token in first project and on second project, I am verifying it.

Comment: That's not relevant. Show the code you use to decode the JWT and pass the signature to the `verify()` method. Provide a sample JWT that fails.

Comment: Thanks @erickson for the reply. I have edited my question.

Comment: Great. I can see that the signature in the sample JWT has the correct length, so the problem is on the parsing and verification side, not the generation. You'd need to show that code to go further.

Comment: I will create a Github project and paste link here.

Comment: @erickson Please take a look at Github project (Link is at the end of the question).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is having same problem, I solved this by following [example](https://gist.github.com/destan/b708d11bd4f403506d6d5bb5fe6a82c5).

I generated my `public`/`private` keys using commands shown [here](https://gist.github.com/destan/b708d11bd4f403506d6d5bb5fe6a82c5/raw/f4fbe2d09337785ea76a48ac76f1c3f6ab4ee7de/generateKeyPair.sh).

and changed following lines (use PRIVATE instead of PUBLIC for `PRIVATE` key)

```
key = key.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLICKEY-----", "").replace("\n", "");
```

to

```
key = key.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
```

It did the magic and works perfectly fine.